# Dynamic row hash based on information_schema for MySQL

Tags: mysql, dynamic, hash, md5, information-schema

We process a large amount of data on a daily basis & one way we reduce processing time is by skipping any records that have not changed from the previous day. We do this by calculating an MD5 hash across all the columns we want to detect changes in & compare it to yesterdays row hash. The problem is that every time we add a column to the load we need to remember to add it to the row hash calculation. This does not always happen & is unnecessary duplicated work. To make this automatic i wanted to use the information schema to build my list of columns dynamically. I spent longer than i would like to admit searching for an answer and eventually building my own. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: it is a matter of SOP to run the hash algorithm after  an alter table. to check run a query that hashes all tables and checks it , if changes occur, then run you row hash, but that should, but for that must be the timing right.

Comment: @nbk This is not for schema changes but rather to detect daily ETL changes automatically instead of defining each column & updating it with each change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set a variable with the dynamic sql so it needs to be done using a procedure. Replace the table name & the excluded columns from the WHERE clause and you should be good to go. This version updates a column called "rowHash" in the same table we are calculating the row hash for but can be modified for other needs.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_set_dynamic_rowhash;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_set_dynamic_rowhash()
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

SET @sql = (SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE TableName SET rowHash = MD5(CONCAT(',GROUP_CONCAT('IFNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(',column_name,')),"")'), '))')
            FROM information_schema.columns 
            WHERE table_name = 'TableName'
            AND table_schema = 'TableSchema'
            AND column_name NOT IN ('excluded_col_1','excluded_col_2','excluded_col_3', 'Rowhash')
           );
         
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END;
```

Comment: the problem with this approach you have to adept the excluision list, a white list don'z t need to be changed

Comment: Sure, i left that open to the developer to adapt with parameters. Maybe im missing something, what do you mean by white list in this case? this is specific to ETL changes.